# Inserting multiple images in MySQL database using for each loop

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert multiple images in the database in the following format,
`09823754257b41f19e24c01471.jpg, 754257b41f19e24c01471422234.jpg,`

I have written the following code to insert the value in the database

```
<?php include "dbconnect.php";

if(isset($_POST['property_add'])){  
$propTitle  = $_POST['title'];
$propSize   = $_POST['size'];
$propType   = $_POST['type'];
$propLoc    = $_POST['location'];
$propStatus = $_POST['status'];
$propPrice  = $_POST['price'];
$propDesc   = $_POST['propDesc'];

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
        $file_name = rand().uniqid().round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  

        $desired_dir="../property/".$propTitle."/".$propStatus."/";
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0777, true);      // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
            rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;                
        }
        if($tmep){
          $photos[] = $file_name;
        }
    }

    $files  =implode(',', $photos);
    $query  =  "INSERT INTO `property`(`property_name`, `property_size`, `property_type`,`property_loc`, `property_status`, `property_price`, `property_desc`, `property_photos`) VALUES ('$propTitle','$propSize','$propType','$propLoc','$propStatus','$propPrice','$propDesc','$files')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    echo "<script>alert('Property Added Successfully')</script>";
    header('Location:../dashboard.php?tab=add&mode=success');
}
}
```

Here the problem is if I selected two images `img1` and `img2` but the above code generates the following value for the files

`09823754257b41f19e24c01471.jpg, 754257b41f19e24c01471422234.jpg,8237542e24c0171422252. ,`

I want the two values only inserted in the database, I don't known why the third value generated.

Comment: do not store this Information as csv. Read about one-to-may relationship

Comment: Is there any other way to work in this code

Comment: @Jens above meant "one to many" relationship, for those of you who wish to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array like this

```
if($tmep){
    $photos[] = $file_name;  //put this code place of $photos .= $file_name." ,";
}
```

and

```
$files = implode(',', $photos);
```

This is return perfect comma-separated value.

Comment: I've changed the code but still the output is shown as **INSERT INTO `property`(`property_name`, `property_size`, `property_type`,`property_loc`, `property_status`, `property_price`, `property_desc`, `property_photos`) VALUES ('Royaal','120Acres','Residential','Bengaluru','Ongoing','80 Lac Onwards','artadtgadg','3109257b42f9760d241471426455.jpg,1602957b42f9760fc11471426455.jpg,1205057b42f97611821471426455.')**

Comment: you are selecting 2 images but loop run 3times

Comment: Thanks Dude.. Still No changes the loop runs Three times

Answer (score 0):

i think this prob happen with file temp. please check how meny temp file generate when upload image (print_r () )
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

i was face prob like this .. i was on temp

thanks

Comment: How did you rectified this problem

Comment: two files only uploading

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my own problem by using `unset` the last array

```
unset($photos[count($photos)-1]);
$files = implode(',', $photos);
```

Thanks guys